# Problem stopping my spider when crawling pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am really new to scrapy module on Python and I have a question regarding my code.

The website I want to scrap contains some data that I want to scrap. In order to do so, my spider crawl on each page and retrieve some data.

My problem is how to make it stop. When loading the last page (page 75), my spider changes the url to go to the 76th, but the website does not display an error or so, but displays page 75 again and again. Here I made it stop by automatically asking to stop when the spider wants to crawl on page 76. But this is not accurate, as the data can change and the website can contains more or less pages over time, not necessarly 75.

Can you help me with this ? I would really appreciate :)

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class TowardsSustainabilitySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "towards_sustainability"
    allowed_domains = ["towardssustainability.be"]
    start_urls = ["https://towardssustainability.be/products?page=1"]
    page_number = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//a[@class="Product-item"]')
        for row in rows:
            fund_name = row.xpath('./div/h2/text()').get()
            yield {
                'fund_name':fund_name
            }

        #go to the next page
        self.page_number+=1
        next_page = f'https://towardssustainability.be/products?page={self.page_number}'
        if next_page == f'https://towardssustainability.be/products?page=76':
            raise CloseSpider
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)`
```

I tried few things out:

-there is a box with the numbers of results on the 1st page. Considering each page contains 10 results, all I had to do was to divide it by ten, then round it up to obtain the number of the last page. Did not work out, I am not pretty sure why..

-just tried 100 different method to make it stop on time: stopping when tuplings in my csv file, trying to match the result of the previous and the current page,...
Nothing made it stop on time

Comment: Do you get redirected to page 75 (i.e. does the url look like `/product?page=75` ?) or does it keep incrementing (`?page=76`, `?page=77`, etc). If you get redirected to 75, you could just keep a list of visited pages and confirm that your next page is not already within that list.

Answer (score 0):

On the page (http response) you can find `next` link. Try to use it.

```
....
next_page = response.css(".Nav-item--next a::attr(href)").get()
if not next_page: 
    raise CloseSpider
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using it, but the spider close itself when crawling page 1... do you have any idea ?

Comment: @AlexisRaphin fixed. Selector was wrong. Use scrapy shell for debugging https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html